# What are the Groups that we can use inside People or Group field .. for example we can not define distribution lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

We are working on an online SharePoint site >> and we added a new field of type People or Group. but my question is which groups we can include inside this field? i tried to add a distribution list but it was not showing? so can anyone advice?

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft support article suggests you can add distribution groups and SharePoint groups...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7

> Include or exclude groups of people    Specify whether the list
> includes only individual people, or additionally includes e-mail
> distribution lists and SharePoint groups.

However my testing indicates you cannot add distribution groups. As far as I can tell, you can add **Azure AD Security Groups**, **Microsoft 365 Groups** and **SharePoint Groups**